# ODBC DSN to SQL Server using Windows NT for another user

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, dsn

I am trying to figure out how/if I can create a DSN on my system to connect to an SQL server so I can use it in MS Access.

- everything is on the `comp` domain
- I log into my workstation as `comp\user1`
- the SQL server was given access to user `comp\user2`
- I am not sure how the SQL server is configured but I cannot change anything

What I've tried:

- if I go into ODBC Administrator and try to create the connection (using either "With Windows NT authentication..." or "With SQL Server authentication...") it **fails**
- if I open the ODBC Administrator as `comp\user2` (shift right click -> open as) then I can **successfully** add the connection using "With Windows NT authentication..."
- but that means I have to open MS Access as `comp\user2` also

I was hoping I could some how add a DSN, user or system, that would use Windows NT authentication as `comp\user2`.

But I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: you can put a user/pass into a dsn, but it's only for retrieving some info from the db and testing the connection while creating the dsn. it won't be used by an app USING the DSN. the app still has to supply the user/pass itself.

Comment: The only way I can put a user/pass into a DSN is if I select `"With SQL Server authentication..."` but then it fails. Is there anyway to tell MS Access to use Windows NT authentication with another ID?